# PowerShell: Find computers that a specific user is logged on with the LastLogonDate

Tags: powershell

Good afternoon,

I would need to run a script that would tell me which computers a particular user was logged into.

I found this script:

```
    #Set variables
$progress = 0

#Get Admin Credentials
Function Get-Login {
Clear-Host
Write-Host "Please provide admin credentials (for example DOMAIN\admin.user and your password)"
$Global:Credential = Get-Credential
}
Get-Login

#Get Username to search for
Function Get-Username {
    Clear-Host
    $Global:Username = Read-Host "Enter username you want to search for"
    if ($Username -eq $null){
        Write-Host "Username cannot be blank, please re-enter username!"
        Get-Username
    }
    $UserCheck = Get-ADUser $Username
    if ($UserCheck -eq $null){
        Write-Host "Invalid username, please verify this is the logon id for the account!"
        Get-Username
    }
}
Get-Username

#Get Computername Prefix for large environments
Function Get-Prefix {
    Clear-Host
    $Global:Prefix = Read-Host "Enter a prefix of Computernames to search on (CXX*) use * as a wildcard or enter * to search on all computers"
    Clear-Host
}
Get-Prefix

#Start search
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Enabled -eq 'true' -and SamAccountName -like $Prefix}
$CompCount = $Computers.Count
Write-Host "Searching for $Username on $Prefix on $CompCount Computers`n"

#Start main foreach loop, search processes on all computers
foreach ($comp in $computers){
    $Computer = $comp.Name
    $Reply = $null
    $Reply = test-connection $Computer -count 1 -quiet
    if($Reply -eq 'True'){
        if($Computer -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME){
            #Get explorer.exe processes without credentials parameter if the query is executed on the localhost
            $proc = gwmi win32_process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -computer $Computer -Filter "Name = 'explorer.exe'"
        }
        else{
            #Get explorer.exe processes with credentials for remote hosts
            $proc = gwmi win32_process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Credential $Credential -computer $Computer -Filter "Name = 'explorer.exe'"
        }           
            #If $proc is empty return msg else search collection of processes for username
        if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($proc)){
            write-host "Failed to check $Computer!"
        }
        else{   
            $progress++         
            ForEach ($p in $proc) {             
                $temp = ($p.GetOwner()).User
                Write-Progress -activity "Working..." -status "Status: $progress of $CompCount Computers checked" -PercentComplete (($progress/$Computers.Count)*100)
                if ($temp -eq $Username){
                write-host "$Username is logged on $Computer"
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
write-host "Search done!"
```

The problem is that I would need it to also tell me the LastLogonDate of that user on those computers found by the script.

I tried several times to add some corrections to the script but i could not achieve it.

Could you help me with this task, please?

Thank so much.

Comment: It would be nice to the author of the script you found if you would add a link to it. Please remove all version tags and leave only the one(s) for the PowerShell versions you are actually using

Comment: @Theo Thank so much to answer me.
This script is in a post from 2015, i will try to contact with the author but i could not it.
Do you have any idea how to do to show also the LastLogonDate?
Thank so much.

Comment: Since your script is returning the **currently** logged on user, you can safely assume the last logon date on that machine is today.. If you really want to see who logged on to a certain machine lately, you will have to look into the Windows Eventlog and look for events in Security with the event ID 4624 (these represent successful login events.). You will need to enable Auditing though. There's a page [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/124313/how-to-see-who-logged-into-a-computer-and-when/) you might want to read

Comment: Finally i could solve it with the "query user" line: query user $Username /server:$Computer

I wouId like to know, to have the perfect script, if, when the "query user" command shows all information: https://ibb.co/jZ6NsF2

I need that it shows only the LOGON TIME information.

Is that possible?

Thank so much.

Comment: I am going to disable the domain administrator account, and i would like to know in what servers this account was used to know the services associated with it.

This scripts works perfect but the problem is that when i try to look for what servers used the administrator account, the servers which appear are related with the local administrator account, not with the domain administrator account.

How could I do that the script look for the servers related with the domain administrator account?

Thank so much.